# Jquery Image Popup Window with thumb nail pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to load an image into a Div when I click on thumbnail image & when I click the image in  Div it should pop-up in a new window (full size image)with all other thumbnail images as navigational pane.
I can load images into a Div & my second requirement is 100% similar to this plugin 
https://41db8e9483f1ef6631809a5ed661fd36970b368a.googledrive.com/host/0B-XtjO0RzRaHbFI0TzFwV2FNYjg/example.html .
But it needs all the anchor "" tags in DIV with thumbnail image sources  to load the thumbnail pane.
Can anyone help me to achieve this or is there any other plugin with a thumbnail pane & popup window?
(ColorBox is Ok but it doesn't have a thumbnail pane)

```
<div class="col-sm-8" style="float:left">
    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
    {
        <div class="gallery-item" id="gallery">
            <a href="~/@image.ImageUrl" class="gallery-tem">
                <img style="max-height:100px; max-width:100p src="~/@image.ThumbNailUrl" class="img-responsive" />
            </a> <br />
        </div>
    }
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" id="imageBox" style=" float:left">
        &nbsp;
        <img src="~/@Model.MainImageUrl" />
    </div>

<script>

$(".gallery-item a").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#imageBox").empty().append(
        $("<img>", { src: this.href })
    );
});
<script/>
```

Comment: You've hundreds of plugins **[here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-gallery/)**

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao
Tx, but  I want thumbnail pane below the popup Image & none of these plugins have that option.

Comment: Gallerie is a simple JQuery plugin that offers a lightbox-like gallery viewer of a collection of images.

Comment: @Chukwuemeka Ihedoro 
yes. The link I priovided is "Gallerie jquery plugin" , but my problem is I can't apply it for the images loaded in imageBox div.